# How to get request query in the same url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, get

I am totally newbie to JavaScript and Express. Now I am trying to build a route to check whether the user's name has already been saved as a cookie in the server if no then the user can fill the form and send it to the server. The name which the user sent would appear in URL and I can use `req.query` to get the name from `http://localhost:3000/trackName?name=aaa`, save it to cookie, redirect to the checking page, and print it on site, done.

However, now I have stuck in the "The name which the user sent would appear in URL and I can use `req.query` to get it and save it to cookie" part, because my program never gets to the second "get" function in my code, I can print out the name I get in the first "get", but the second part would never run in the console, neither the browser.

Here is my code:

```js
router.get('/myName', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.cookies.username;
    if (name) {
        console.log(name);
        res.render('myName', {name: name});
    } else {
        console.log("else");
        res.render('myName');
    }
});


router.post('/myName', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/trackName');
});

router.get('/trackName', (req, res) => {    
    console.log(req.query.name); // here I can print out the name I got from form in terminal 'aaa'
    return res.render('trackName');
    
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.name); // This part never appeared in terminal

    res.cookie('name', req.query.name);
    res.redirect('/myName');
})


router.post('/goodbye', (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('name');
    res.redirect('/myName');
});
```

Also, here is my pug form for getting name:

```
doctype html 
html(lang="en")
    head 
        title My Server
    body 
    block content 
        if name 
            h2 username: #{name}
            form(action='/goodbye', method='post')
                button(type='submit') Goodbye
        else   
            form(action='/trackName', method='get')
                label Please enter your name: 
                    input(type='text', name='name')
                button(type='submit') Submit
```

Have tried fiddling around for a long while but still failed...
Could somebody help me  some keywords or methods to search?

**Update:**
I tried @jfriend00 's suggestion to modify the `/trackName` to `/name` in my HTML form in order to make `router.get('/:id', ...` run, but now I got URL `http://localhost:3000/name?name=aaa` which is not I want, and still the `router.get('/:id', ...` doesn't get the query either...

Comment: @jfriend00 Now I do have the URL like this: `trackName?name=aaa` , but it stuck in the `http://localhost:3000/trackName?name=aaa` url and not redirecting..

Comment: @jfriend00 sry I just edit my question and add the goodbye part

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried to use `res.send()` instead of `res.render()` to make browser get `router.get('/:id', (req, res)` part and get the name in url now: `trackName?name=aaa` but the `req.query.name` in `router.get('/:id', (req, res)` still not get triggered

Comment: @jfriend00 The url I want to hit `router.get('/:id',  ...)` is `http://localhost:3000/trackName?name=aaa` , is it available..?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, it works like that... If I want to get that URL, then maybe should open another route `trackName` or modify the `/:id` to `/trackName:id`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for further question, could you please explain it more? Changing the URL means trying to change `/:id` part to not match `/trackName` , is it? However the URL after I send the form, the name automatically appear in URL like `http://localhost:3000/trackName?name=aaa`, could you specify the part which you means to change?

Comment: I can't help any more.  Have to go do other things now.